# How to use World Wind Java SDK offline

Tags: java, worldwind

I'm trying to use World Wind, it is really  good and very easy to edit.

But in my condition, the application is  needed to be run offline.

So we  can run the WorlWind offline ?

http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Comment: If you mean offline from Internet but online through LAN, it does support local cache server http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=16670 http://worldwindcentral.com/wiki/Data_serving_scripts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set

```
gov.nasa.worldwind.avkey.OfflineMode
```

in the WorldWind properties file. This will stop WorldWind from trying to download tiles, and it will rely on the local cache only.

However, you may need to populate the local cache either by browsing over a particular area of interest, or installing cache packs.

Unfortunately, the site (http://www.worldwinddata.com/), that used to host cache packs, is no longer running (domain has expired).

Comment: How to install cache packs in world wind??

Comment: As as far as I remember, you find where WorldWind's tile directory is (see [this discussion](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?24069-where-is-the-cache-folder)), then just uncompress the pack into this folder to match the existing structure. I don't have WW installed currently so can't check.

Comment: Thanks.. The default cache folder in Windows is `C:\ProgramData\WorldWindData` I extracted my cache data in this folder and its working fine... Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Where can you get the cache packs?

Comment: Sadly the cache packs no longer seem to be available from http://www.worldwinddata.com/; I don't know of a new source at present